# Grammar of two consecutive "if" constructions?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If you walk up to your husband and say, "I will never relinquish control of the household!", he'll be so kind **if** **he** **only** **says**, "Honey, relinquish is just a fancy word for give up."

1. Is the above sentence grammatically correct?
2. Can the part in boldface be replaced with **to** **only** **say** without loss of meaning?
3. Is there any other way to say this without using two *if* constructions?

Comment: I think *Imagine ...; Suppose ...*; or *Let's say ...* are reasonable substitutes for the first *If*. (Note that you'll need to break the sentence into two if you do the substitution.)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been thinking of. Thank you!

Comment: To be "kind" means to be considerate, thoughtful, benevolent and helpful. Why is the husband's reply "kind? I see nothing helpful or generous about it. Are you saying  (in your culture) his response would be considered polite?

Comment: There are three things about the wife's statement that would trigger an aggressive response by most men:
1. She is taking a daring, rude tone of voice -- "will never".
2. She is trying to come off as smart -- "relinquish".
3. She is trying to hijack her husband's inherent right of being in control.
A man refusing to pick up the gauntlet,  giving a humorous off-topic response is one who cares about his wife.

Comment: A second "if" might be replaced by the word "provided" in some sentences, but the sentence in this question needs much more thought as noted in the previous comments.

Comment: I think I've explained that.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are grammatically correct, but they mean different things. In the original way you make a judgement that he is kind if he says whay he says, but you are also implying that he could say other things. If you replace **if he only says** with **to only say** you are telling the audience that he will say this, like in a forecast, maybe not what you intended to say.

Cookie Monster's suggestion **he would be kind, saying** is a good way of keeping the same meaning, but avoiding the use of *if* twice. Like him, I'd also leave out *so*. And *to say* or *saying* is pretty much equivalent here, though I prefer *to say*. Note the use of *would* instead of *will*, which makes it conditional instead of forecasting.

Comment: But this is a first conditional ( if you say, he will) how can _would_ be correct?

Comment: By using _would_ you are talking about a possible outcome. Using _will_ you are predicting what will happen. If you want to predict, use will. If you want to illustrate a possible outcome, use would. Damkerng. T. also makes a good point and you should definitely consider that option!

Comment: No one ever told me this. Beautifuly explained. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I'm still confused. This sentence gives me much trouble. I want to say: If he says _only_ this (and not anything offensive), he will be so kind. I'm making a judgement that he is kind on that condition. Having given your reply a second thought, I think _he_ _is_ _kind_ _if_ _he_ _only_ _says_ would be better because I'm neither making a prediction nor talking about a possible outcome, I'm making a judgment about him if he says this and nothing more (like: How dare you says this, you bi***!)

Comment: Yes, I do agree, using if captures what you want to say best. In that case I would definitely write it like this: **Imagine** you walk up to your husband and say, "I will never relinquish control of the household!", he'll be (so) kind if he only says, "Honey, relinquish is just a fancy word for give up."

Answer (score -2):

That second *if* in your sentence makes it sound like he will be kind only under the condition that he says "Honey, relinquish is just a fancy word for give up." I don't think that's what you want to say.

I would rewrite you sentence like this:

> If you approach your husband and say, "I will never relinquish control of the household!", he'd be kind saying "Honey, relinquish is just a fancy word for give up".

The sentence is still awkward, in my opinion, because I'm not sure why do you have to be kind saying something like that?

Comment: This is an example of a fancy word that people should avoid in their relaxed conversations. The fact that men are usually in control of a household makes the husband's reply a kind one when he only focuses on an off-topic, funny thing as pointing out the fanciness of "relinquish" instead of focusing on the issue at hand.

Comment: Then I'd simply go with the fallowing: "he'll probably just say"